# How to make a responsive background in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How to make a background like this one?[sample](http://sophiaamercado.weebly.com/blog).
[Here's mine](http://pastebin.com/HZBMgQbV).
Can somebody help me achieving a responsive background similar to this one.
Thanks!

Comment: i mention my code in my post... and ive already tried that i know to search via google.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `background-size: cover;`.

```css
body {
    background-image: url('http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/094/491/original/polygonal-texture-background-vector.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

 .content{
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<a href="index.html"><button type='button' id='viewSubjectRating' class="button_position">Home</button></a>

<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for quick responce :) .ive do a lot of research for this but i cannot find the best answer for my question.

Comment: @KennyTan Is the tick that is on the left of my answer. When it puts green after press it you have accepted the answer and it will give to you +2 points.

Answer (score 0):

Do `background-size: cover;.` more info at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)